# Angular-in-memory-web-api Error angular2 M

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I'm working with angular2 project,I have an error when I import

```
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
```

in package.json file its  `"angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.3.1"` version.
in product.module.ts i've import this, and i've set at import section, but if i remove , my project loaded with no problem.

```
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { ProductData } from './product-data'

..
  // modules which are used by above components
    imports: [
        SharedModule, // shared module    
        InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(ProductData, { delay: 1500 }),
```

error is :

> Object { __zone_symbol__error: Error, fileName: Getter, lineNumber:
>   Getter, columnNumber: Getter, message: Getter, name: Getter, stack:
>   Getter, originalStack: Getter, zoneAwareStack: Getter, toString:
>   createMethodProperty/props[key].value(), 4 more… }

My product data class it is :

```
        import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular2-in-memory-web-api';
    import { IProduct } from './product';
    export class ProductData implements InMemoryDbService {

        createDb() {
            let products: IProduct[] = [
                {
     'id': 1,
                    'productName': 'test',
                    'productCode': 't01'
    }
];
     return { products };
        }
    }
```

In systemjs.config.js file i have add in map section :

```
   'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api'
```

also       `'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }`
Can you help me to fix that problem?

Comment: can you share product data class? and also system js config file?

Comment: @KaranGarg yes ofcourse, product data class:                                               export interface IProduct {
    id: number;
    productName: string;
    productCode: string;
    tags?: string[];
    releaseDate: string;
    price: number;
    description: string;
    starRating: number;
    imageUrl: string;
}

Comment: this is your product interface i meant product class.because in your product class you need to implement InMemoryDbService and then call method createDb()

Comment: you have right, i edited my question , the product data class is there

Comment: you are missing one closing bracket ( ] )after 'productCode': 't01'} in your product class

Comment: no, i check this file and its ok

Comment: i have error when i add          InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(ProductData, { delay: 1500 }), in import section in product.module.ts

Comment: May you create minimal plunker example for your Angular2 code? Angular2 errors are far from being clear. We need to reproduce your problem somehow.

You can use some boilerplate like http://embed.plnkr.co/xTyGA7Klq8Mta2T1yANh/.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve